# PHP match two values from two different arrays in random shuffle function

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in PHP. One is a list of numbers that I generate between 1 and 24 and shuffle them using PHP (see below).

```
$numbers = range(1, 24);
        shuffle($numbers);
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {
                echo "<h5>$number</h5>";
        }
```

Every time I load the page this gives me a list of numbers randomly shuffled each time.

I have another array with 24 URLs

```
$links = array(         "http://www.linkone.co.uk",
                        "http://www.linktwo.co.uk",
                        "http://etc.co.uk"
                        ); .....
```

Is there a way I can assign say number 15 to URL number 15 no matter where it is generated in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign specific keys:

```
$links = array( 15 => "http://www.linkone.co.uk",
                16 => "http://www.linktwo.co.uk", ); //etc...
```